# Ajuda Script VBA para excel

Tags: vba, excel-vba

estou desenvolvendo um script para Excel, que copia campos específicos de uma planilha, e cola em outra, pega o nome da célula A9 e salva um arquivos com os dados copiados com o nome da célula A9 em formato .txt, após deleta a linha A9 e continua o loop ate que chegue na célula A9 sem valores, o script para isso funciona como eu quero, mas estou quebrando a cabeça é para salvar esse .txt dentro da pasta que tambem o script cria com nome da célula A9.

EX: C:\user\desktop\saves\001\001.txt,
C:\user\desktop\saves\002\002.txt,
C:\user\desktop\saves\003\003.txt e assim por diante.

alguém poderia me ajudar?

abaixo o codigo que estou usando:

```
Sub CriarNovaPlanilha()
    
 linha = 9
 
 Do Until Cells(linha, 1) = ""
    
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    ' declara as variáveis
    
    Dim ultimaPlanilha As Integer
    Dim planilhaVerificada As Integer

    ' define a última planilha com nome Dados encontrada,
    ' o 0 (zero) indica que ainda não foi encontrada
    
    ultimaPlanilha = 0

    ' desativa atualização de tela
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' adiciona nova planilha no final
    
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

    ' percorre todas as planilhas existentes
    
    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count Step 1
        ' verifica os nomes das planilhas
        If Sheets(i).Name = "Dados" And ultimaPlanilha = 0 Then
            ' define que foi encontrada uma planilha com nome Dados
            ultimaPlanilha = 1
        ElseIf Sheets(i).Name Like "Dados (*)" Then
            ' pega o número que está entre os parênteses
            planilhaVerificada = CInt(Mid(Sheets(i).Name, 6, Len(Sheets(i).Name) - 6))

            ' verifica o número da planilha atual com o número da última encontrada
            If planilhaVerificada > ultimaPlanilha Then
                ' define o número da última planilha encontrada
                ultimaPlanilha = planilhaVerificada
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    ' seleciona a planiha atual
    
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Select

    ' verifica qual o nome deverá ser considerado
    
    If ultimaPlanilha = 0 Then
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = "Dados"
    Else
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = "Dados (" & CStr(ultimaPlanilha + 1) & ")"
    End If

    ' ativa atualização de tela
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True



'Cria a pasta com o nome da Celula A9

     Dim pasta As Object, nomePasta

        Set pasta = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

            On Error Resume Next

    nomePasta = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Planilha1.Cells(9, 1).Value

        If Not pasta.FolderExists(nomePasta) Then
            pasta.CreateFolder (nomePasta)
        End If

'Copia os dados definidos da plan1

    Sheets("plan1").Select
    
    Dim Nome As String
    
    Nome = Planilha1.Range("A9").Text
 
    Range("C1:C6").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Dados").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("plan1").Select
    Range("A9").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Dados").Select
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("plan1").Select
    Range("C9").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Dados").Select
    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("plan1").Select
    Range("E9").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Dados").Select
    Range("B3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("plan1").Select
    Range("F9").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Dados").Select
    Range("B4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("plan1").Select
    Range("G9").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Dados").Select
    Range("B5").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("plan1").Select
    Range("H9").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Dados").Select
    Range("B6").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Dados").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheets("Dados").Move
     
    'Salva os dados copiados em formato .txt 
    
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\arthu\Desktop\save\" & Nome & ".txt", _
        FileFormat:=xlUnicodeText, CreateBackup:=False

    
    ActiveWindow.Close
    Rows("9:9").Select
    Range("G9").Activate
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    
    Loop

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá!

Como vai?

Eu testei seu código (obviamente, adaptando para salvar os arquivos nas minhas pastas) e o resultado foi que o código criou uma pasta com o valor da célula A9 na mesma pasta em que a planilha estava salva e o arquivo .txt foi salvo em outra pasta dentro do " C:\ " .

Pelo o que eu entendi da sua pergunta, você quer salvar o .txt dentro da pasta criada com o valor da célula A9 (que é criada no mesmo caminho da planilha que realiza essa operação). É isso?

Se for, só o que você precisa fazer é alterar o caminho em que o .txt é salvo. É só fazer isso:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=nomePasta & "\" & Nome & ".txt", _
        FileFormat:=xlUnicodeText, CreateBackup:=False
```

Isso porque a variável "nomePasta" armazenou o caminho da pasta criada com o valor da célula A9.

Originalmente, a sua planilha estava direcionando para salvar o .txt em uma nova pasta chamada "save" dentro do " C:\ " no final do código.

Se sua intenção, por outro lado, for criar a pasta com o valor da célula A9 dentro da pasta "save", você também precisará mudar o código atribuído à variável "nomePasta" para:

```
C:\Users\arthu\Desktop\save\
```

No lugar de:

```
ThisWorkbook.Path
```

Se não der certo, me avise aqui.